# How to find field names using ijson in python?

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to convert large json file to csv ,how to use ijson package in python to access all the field names in json file without specifying field names in the code?

Comment: Do you want to iterate all prefixes?

Comment: Can you provide short example of JSON data and describe what you expect as result?

Comment: JSON in Python is very simple. Say `json.loads(string)` and you get a standard `dict` or `list` that you can do normal Python things with. You can get the keys of a `dict` with `dict.keys()`.

Comment: yes,i want to iterate all prefixes.